# FreeBSD Terminal couldn't found sdk command

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, freebsd

I want to use kotlin language on my freebsd system. I installed sdkman with this commands:

```
 $curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

after that, i write that command

```
sdk install kotlin
```

but terminal doesnt execute sdk command. It couldn't found sdk command. What should I do, I remove twice time sdkman and install, but i couldn't be succeed

Answer (score 0):

You can follow recommendation from output:

```
Please open a new terminal, or run the following in the existing one:

    source "/home/user/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

Then issue the following command:

    sdk help

Enjoy!!!
```

For me "source" command works fine:

```
[user@host ~]$ source /home/user/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh
[user@host ~]$ sdk
==== BROADCAST =================================================================
* 07/09/17: Gradle 4.2-rc-1 released on SDKMAN! #gradle
* 07/09/17: Groovy 2.6.0-alpha-1 released on SDKMAN! #groovylang
* 30/08/17: Kotlin 1.1.4-3 released on SDKMAN! #kotlin
================================================================================

Usage: sdk <command> [candidate] [version]
       sdk offline <enable|disable>

   commands:
       install   or i    <candidate> [version]
       uninstall or rm   <candidate> <version>
       list      or ls   [candidate]
       use       or u    <candidate> [version]
       default   or d    <candidate> [version]
       current   or c    [candidate]
       upgrade   or ug   [candidate]
       version   or v
       broadcast or b
       help      or h
       offline           [enable|disable]
       selfupdate        [force]
       flush             <candidates|broadcast|archives|temp>

   candidate  :  the SDK to install: groovy, scala, grails, gradle, kotlin, etc.
                 use list command for comprehensive list of candidates
                 eg: $ sdk list

   version    :  where optional, defaults to latest stable if not provided
                 eg: $ sdk install groovy

[user@host ~]$ type sdk
sdk is a function
sdk () 
...
```

I've opened new terminal and it works fine without "source" command.
My uname:

```
uname -a
FreeBSD host 12.0-CURRENT FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT #2 r321414: Mon Jul 24 21:41:54 MSK 2017     user@host:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

If any problem still exists, please share more details (output of commands, "type sdk", your environment details incl. desktop environment version and configuration).